# Why is Maxwell-Boltzmann velocity distribution not uniform?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

Consider a particle moving in one dimension by discrete jumps with two options at a time and starting at the origin at time zero. Each time, the particle can jump by a small distance to the left or to the right. If we count the number of possible options that the particle has to arrive at some position x after some time t, then the number of options to stay near the origin will be large, and the number of options to drift away from the origin will be small. For example to stay exactly at the origin after four steps, the particle has the options (+1,+1,-1,-1), (+1,-1,+1,-1), and so on. While it has only one single option (+1,+1,+1,+1) to achieve four units.

Now if we take the limit of continuous time and take the real axis, the probability of finding the particle at position x after time t will be a gaussian distribution with mean zero and variance proportional to the square root of time. Thus, this example explains how an initial Dirac distribution is smoothed to a gaussian by statistical arguments. However, in this example we observe that the gaussian continues to broaden as a function of time due to the increasing variance, until it becomes a uniform distribution.

Finally I arrive to my question. I went through many derivations of Maxwell-Boltzmann velocity distribution. But I am still not able to explain why this distribution does not broaden to a uniform distribution based on the simple intuition explained above.

More generally, the positions of particles undergro this kind of motion by a rate given by the diffusion coefficient. However, momentum also diffuses by a rate give by the viscosity. Shouldn't this diffusion also imply a uniform distribution ?

Comment: Well, there are two issues with your argument. First, you're talking about how the particle's _position_ changes, and in equilibrium the position is uniform, just as your argument expects. Second, if you try to apply the same argument to how the particle's _velocity_ changes, then it doesn't work, because it isn't true that each change in the velocity is independent of the rest. If a particle has a high speed, then it's more likely to lose speed in a collision than to gain it.

Comment: Can you follow up on why you think the velocity distribution should diffuse? This seems to me to violate conservation of energy.

Comment: Also no. The fact that momentum diffuses means that if a gas has no net momentum, then in equilibrium each gas molecule has zero average velocity. That doesn’t tell you what the speed distribution is.

Comment: You might also say that energy diffuses, which is also true, but that merely says that the speed distribution is the same throughout the container of gas. It doesn’t tell you what the speed distribution for each molecule is.

Comment: At infinite temperature, the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution becomes uniform in some sense. Isn't your question rather why it is non uniform in certain temperatures?